# Simpest way to traspile and import TypeScript file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

What is the simpest way to traspile and import TypeScript in nodeJS?

I do not want to use any global `tsc` compilers installed as I have pure JS server with classic commonJS modules. The only problem - shared environment settings as single typescript file for client (Angular2) and server.

So I need only single file to be transpilled in node to share common settings. Maybe there is some effective in-memory transpiller?

I want smth like this:

```
var transpiller = require('some-magic-tarnspiller');
var evn = transpiller('environments/environment.ts');
```

Comment: You mean like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler ?

Comment: Like this, but use file path as argument. But anyway thanks.